# Liquibase not logging change sets in Postgresql Database

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to use liquibase for postgresql database versioning and followed the  given in official link.

1. Created a test database and added a tag="baseline" using commandline . This was recorded in the Changelog table.

   > ```
   > liquibase --driver= org.postgresql.Driver --classpath=./lib/postgresql-42.2.5.jar --url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/lpoc --username=postgres --password=emr123 tag=baseline
   >
   > Successfully tagged postgres@jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/lpoc
   > Liquibase 'tag' Successful
   > ```
2. Created  a table  and added columns into it. This was not recorded as a change set in the Changelog table .
   [image: Changelog table after a table is created]
3. When added a new column to the newly created  table, it is not showing as a changeset tag when checked in changelog.xml file and also in changelog table .

Comment: So what exactly is the contents of your `changeSet` that you run in set 2.?

Comment: I added one more column to the newly created table. 
 `alter table xx add column abc type text`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete changeLog and the exact Liquibase command line you used to run that changeLog ([edit] your question, do not post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Did you add the table and column using liquibase or did you add it using the postgres gui or command line? (I am also seconding the request that you edit your question to add those details.)